# Как реализовать ScrollBar для Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

Вот кусок кода:

```
   canvas = tkinter.Canvas(borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
   frame= tkinter.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
   vsb = tkinter.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
   canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
   vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
   canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
   canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=frame, anchor="nw")
```

далее в frame циклом добавляю канва-объекты, они уходят за пределы экрана, но скролл так и остается неактивным. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы "активировать" scrollbar надо канве указать сколлируемый регион.
Если не требуется сложных вычислений, то проще всего это сделать двумя командами после размещения/изменения элементов канвы:

```
canvas.update_idletasks() # чтобы дать возможность установиться всем размерам
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Полный код для примера:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
frame= tkinter.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
vsb = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=frame, anchor="nw")

for i in range(20):
    lbl = tkinter.Label(frame, text=f"Label {i}")
    lbl.pack(side="top")

canvas.update_idletasks() 
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: -]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!