# Как использовать scrollbar в Tkinter Python 3 для вывода списка из БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, scrollbar

Пытаюсь установить **scrollbar** на базе **Tkinter** (Python 3) в GUI своей программы (самодельная бд), пока что не получается победить. Выводится рамка **scrollbar**-а без бегунка, но даже рамка выводится не на высоту отображаемого окна, а на всю высоту выведенного списка, часть которого скрыта из-за разрешения окна. Прикрепляю скриншот.

[image: Скрин1]

Графический интерфейс должен выводить список из БД, можно отметить галочками строки, по нажатию на пелпк исправить или подтвердить строки меняют статус, идея очень простая.

Начитавшись форумов пришел к выводу что нужно использовать frame_main для всего окна, в нем будут установлены `grid`-ом `frame_canvas` и кнопки, а уже в `frame_canvas pack` будут установлены canvas для вывода списка из БД и **scrollbar**.

Прикрепляю мою схему моей логики:

[image: Схема]

Но по итогу отображается лишь рамка без бегунка, а также высота рамки отображена на всю высоту списка, и не ограничена высотой окна интерфейса.

[image: Скрин2]

Подскажите, в чем я не прав и помогите победить **scrollbar**.

Код функции:

```
def admintable();
import pickle
global flsp1, root4, kolivanov, kolpetrov;

 ...
root4=Tk()
root4.geometry(‘1100x900-0-0’)
root4.title(“Администратор”)

frame_main=Frame(root4)
frame_main.grid(row=0, column=0)

frame_canvas=Frame(frame_main)
frame_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

canvas=Canvas(frame_canvas)
canvas.pack(side=RIGHT)

scroll_canv=Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient=VERTICAL)
scroll_canv.pack(side=LEFT, fill=“y”)
scroll_canv.config(command=canvas.yview)

 <вывод списка из бд в canvas> 

but_0=Button(frame_main, text=‘Подтвердить’, command=ispoladm)
but_1=Button(frame_main, text=‘Исправить’, command=ispolndm_ipsr)
but_0.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=‘nw’)
but_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

fraim_main.config(width=1100, height=900)
fraim_canvas.config(width=1000, height=600)
canvas.config(width=1100, height=500, yscrollcommand=scroll_canv.set)

root4.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример кода как у вас добавляются строки в "таблицу" (код добавления одной строки в таблицу), чтобы можно было у себя воспроизвести проблему. Также желательно поправить отступы и кавычки (с теми кавычками что в вопросе код работать не будет), а также определиться с именами переменных (у вас fraim или frame все-таки?)

Comment: Возможные дубликаты: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1095489/1365, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1333158/1365

Comment: Вообще, конечно, удобнее было бы использовать Treeview, а не изобретать табличный контрол заново.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает Scrollbar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095489/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

Вот в качестве примера.

```
import tkinter as tk

root4 = tk.Tk()
root4.geometry("800x600")

frame_main = tk.Frame(root4)
frame_main.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

frame_canvas = tk.Frame(frame_main)
frame_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_canvas, width=300)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

scroll_canv = tk.Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scroll_canv.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
scroll_canv.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_canv.set)

frame_buttons = tk.Frame(frame_main)
frame_buttons.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

but_0 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Подтвердить")
but_0.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=15, pady=(15, 5))
but_1 = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Исправить")
but_1.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=15, pady=5)

# <вывод списка из бд в canvas> 
for i in range(100):
    canvas.create_text((5, i*18), text=f"Text {i+1} "*(i*87%13+2), fill="#"+f"{i*7%128:0>2x}{i*27%111:0>2x}{i*41%113:0>2x}", anchor="nw")

# !!! следующие 2 строки очень важны для корректного отображения скроллбара !!!
canvas.update_idletasks() 
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root4.mainloop()
```

[image: -]